# Python Pandas equivalent in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python

With this CSV example:

```
   Source,col1,col2,col3
   foo,1,2,3
   bar,3,4,5
```

The standard method I use Pandas is this:

1. Parse CSV
2. Select columns into a data frame (`col1` and `col3`)
3. Process the column (e.g. avarage the values of  `col1` and `col3`)

Is there a JavaScript library that does that like Pandas?

Answer (score 231, accepted):

This wiki will summarize and compare many pandas-like Javascript libraries.

In general, you should check out the d3 JavaScript library. d3 is very useful "swiss army knife" for handling data in JavaScript, just like pandas is helpful for Python. You may see d3 used frequently like pandas, even if d3 is not exactly a DataFrame/Pandas replacement (i.e. d3 doesn't have the same API; d3 does not have `Series` / `DataFrame` classes with methods that match the pandas behavior).

[Ahmed's answer explains how d3 can be used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30611208/1175496)  to achieve some DataFrame functionality, and some of the libraries below were inspired by things like [LearnJsData](http://learnjsdata.com/) which uses d3 and lodash.

As for DataFrame-style data transformation (splitting, joining, group by etc), here is a quick list of some of the JavaScript libraries.

Note the libraries are written in different languages, including...

- browser-compatible aka client-side JavaScript
- Node.js aka Server-side JavaScript
- Typescript
- Some even use CPython transpiled to WebAssembly (but work with Node.js and/or browsers)

...so use the option that's right for you:

- [Pyodide](https://pyodide.org) ([browser-support AND Nodejs-support](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/project/about.html))

  - A new but very strong contender from [Ahmed Fasih's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75226873)
  - WebAssembly transpilation of CPython and a large portion of the numeric Python ecosystem ("including NumPy, pandas, SciPy, Matplotlib, and scikit-learn") "for the browser and Node.js "
  - made by folks tightly connected to Project Jupyter
  - see its [list of included packages](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/usage/packages-in-pyodide.html)
- [danfo-js](https://danfo.jsdata.org/) ([browser-support AND NodeJS-support](https://danfo.jsdata.org/getting-started))

  - From [Vignesh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64026315/1175496)
  - danfo (which is often imported and aliased as `dfd`); has a basic DataFrame-type data structure, with the ability to plot directly
  - Built by the [team at Tensorflow](https://blog.tensorflow.org/2020/08/introducing-danfo-js-pandas-like-library-in-javascript.html#:%7E:text=Data%20Science%20Nigeria-,Danfo.,provides%20a%20similar%20interface%2FAPI.): "One of the main goals of Danfo.js is to bring data processing, machine learning and AI tools to JavaScript developers. ... Open-source libraries like Numpy and Pandas..."
  - pandas is built on top of numpy; likewise danfo-js is built on tensorflow-js
  - please note danfo may **not** (yet?) support [multi-column indexes](https://github.com/javascriptdata/danfojs/issues/496)
- [pandas-js](https://stratodem.github.io/pandas.js-docs/#introduction)

  - **UPDATE** The pandas-js repo has not been  updated in awhile
  - From [STEEL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50055338/1175496) and [Feras](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57166246/1175496)' answers
  - "pandas.js is an open source (experimental) library mimicking the Python pandas library. It relies on Immutable.js as the NumPy logical equivalent. The main data objects in pandas.js are, like in Python pandas, the Series and the DataFrame."
- [dataframe-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dataframe-js)

  - "DataFrame-js provides an immutable data structure for javascript and datascience, the DataFrame, which allows to work on rows and columns with a sql and functional programming inspired api."
- [data-forge](https://github.com/data-forge/data-forge-ts)

  - Seen in [Ashley Davis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41605498/1175496)
  - "JavaScript data transformation and analysis toolkit inspired by Pandas and LINQ."
  - Note the [old data-forge JS repository](https://github.com/data-forge/data-forge-js) is no longer maintained; now a new repository uses Typescript
- [jsdataframe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdataframe)

  - "Jsdataframe is a JavaScript data wrangling library inspired by data frame functionality in R and Python Pandas."
- [dataframe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dataframe)

  - "explore data by grouping and reducing."
- [SQL Frames](https://sqlframes.com/)

  - "DataFrames meet SQL, in the Browser"
  - "SQL Frames is a low code data management framework that can be directly embedded in the browser to provide rich data visualization and UX. Complex DataFrames can be composed using familiar SQL constructs. With its powerful built-in analytics engine, data sources can come in any shape, form and frequency and they can be analyzed directly within the browser. It allows scaling to big data backends by transpiling the composed DataFrame logic to SQL."
- [Jandas](https://github.com/frlender/Jandas) (browser- AND NodeJS-support; a new TypeScript library developed in 2023)

  - Indexing and query very similar to Pandas
  - Negative number and range indexing
  - Support DataFrame with zero rows/columns
  - Support index with duplicated values
  - iterrows, sort_values, groupby and element-wise operation

Then after coming to this question, checking other answers here and doing more searching, I found options like:

- [Apache Arrow in JS](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/js/)

  - Thanks to user Back2Basics suggestion:
  - "Apache Arrow is a columnar memory layout specification for encoding vectors and table-like containers of flat and nested data. Apache Arrow is the emerging standard for large in-memory columnar data (Spark, **Pandas**, Drill, Graphistry, ...)"
- [polars](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars)

  - Polars is a blazingly fast DataFrames library *implemented in Rust* using [Apache Arrow Columnar Format](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/format/Columnar.html) as memory model.
- [Observable](https://beta.observablehq.com/)

  - At first glance, seems like a `JS` alternative to the IPython/Jupyter ["notebooks"](https://ipython.org/notebook.html)
  - Observable's page promises: "Reactive programming", a "Community", on a "Web Platform"
  - See 5 minute intro [here](https://beta.observablehq.com/@mbostock/five-minute-introduction)
- [portal.js](https://github.com/datopian/portal.js) (formerly `recline`; from [Rufus' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34564020/1175496))

  - **MAY BE OUTDATED:** Does not use a "DataFrame" API
  - **MAY BE OUTDATED:** Instead emphasizes its "Multiview" (the UI) API,  (similar to jQuery/DOM model) which doesn't require jQuery but does require a browser! [More examples](http://okfnlabs.org/recline/demos/multiview/)
  - **MAY BE OUTDATED:** Also emphasizes its [MVC-ish architecture](http://okfnlabs.org/recline/docs/); including back-end stuff (i.e. database connections)
- [js-data](http://www.js-data.io/)

  - Really more of an [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)! Most of [its modules](http://api.js-data.io/) correspond to different data **storage** questions (`js-data-mongodb`, `js-data-redis`, `js-data-cloud-datastore`), sorting, filtering, etc.
  - On plus-side does work on Node.js as a first-priority; "Works in Node.js and in the Browser."
- [miso](https://web.archive.org/web/20171213200500/http://misoproject.com/dataset/) (another suggestion from [Rufus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34564020/1175496))

  - Impressive backers like [Guardian](http://www.guardian.co.uk/profile/guardian-interactive-department) and [bocoup](https://bocoup.com/).
- [AlaSQL](https://github.com/agershun/alasql)

  - "AlaSQL" is an open source SQL database for Javascript with a strong focus on query speed and data source flexibility for both relational data and schemaless data. It works in your browser, Node.js, and Cordova."
- Some thought experiments:

  - ["Scaling a DataFrame in Javascript" - Gary Sieling](https://www.garysieling.com/blog/scaling-a-dataframe-in-javascript)

Here are the criteria we used to consider the above choices

- General Criteria

  - Language (NodeJS vs  browser JS vs Typescript)
  - Dependencies (i.e. if it uses an underlying library / AJAX/remote API's)
  - Actively supported (active user-base, active source repository, etc)
  - Size/speed of JS library
- *Panda's criterias in its [R comparison](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/comparison_with_r.html)*

  - Performance
  - Functionality/flexibility
  - Ease-of-use
- Similarity to Pandas / Dataframe API's

  - Specifically hits on their [main features](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas#main-features)
  - Data-science emphasis
  - Built-in visualization functions
  - Demonstrated integration in combination with other tools like Jupyter (interactive notebooks), etc

Comment: Thanks for this wonderful overview. I know both the use of pandas dataframes and SQL. What are the advantages (and disadvantages) of using JS using dataframes versus a JS SQL database?

Comment: @molotow this is a great question, but I don't have much experience with JS SQL databases (though they look cool). In general I would *guess* that dataframe-type approaches would support more "data wrangling" / "data-science" focused functions, like inferring empty values; doing matrix multiplication, etc. Whereas a (JS) SQL is more focused on relational stuff: querying, sorting, filtering. Of course there will be overlap; dataframe can JOIN, sort, and filter, just like SQL includes some statistical functions and etc. Anyone else have ideas?

Comment: Thanks, @Back2Basics , I included in the answer! Apache Arrow seems like a great option because it explicitly mentions Pandas, in-memory columnar data, and Apache Arrow itself is used /contributed by pandas creator, Wes McKinney: [Why pandas users should be excited about Apache Arrow](http://wesmckinney.com/blog/pandas-and-apache-arrow/)

Comment: the fact that there are so many options is annoying. Rather have the community focused on one thing only and make it good.

Comment: (Arrow JS author here) @ClaudiuCreanga I understand the frustration. Initially we wrote ArrowJS in an attempt to bridge the divide between node/browsers and more traditional big-data stacks, and we've invested most heavily in excellent IPC/streaming primitives so far. As next steps, we'd love to start integrating with more JS libs (tensorflow, d3, etc.), and PRs are always welcome. An alternative approach is things like [JPMC's Perspective](https://github.com/finos/perspective/) project, which uses ArrowJS to consume and produce Arrow tables.

Comment: is there a functionality for the dataframe merge in pandas equivalent in javascript ?

Comment: Recline links return 404, so the project either got moved (could not find it) or was discontinued (more likely)

Comment: Thanks, @Shadow , I renamed it to "Portal" ; according to the Portal GitHub repository: What happened to Recline?
Portal.JS used to be Recline(JS). If you are looking for the old Recline codebase it still exists: see the recline branch. If you want context for the rename see this issue.

Comment: I would like to suggest [SQL Frames](http://sqlframes.com). It uses SQL constructs for data transformation logic. It has integrated tabular UI and charts. Has the ability to generate SQL against different databases based on the logic used to compose the data frames.

Comment: [polars](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars) is available in Node.js It is likely the most performant and feature complete option in Nodejs.

Comment: What of those suggestions work in the browser and not only in nodejs?

Comment: Hi @Stefan maybe we can check the documentation link and update the community answer to specify *browser*, *NodeJS*, or *both*. For example, I checked [danfo](https://danfo.jsdata.org/getting-started), and it has instructions for NodeJs applications, and for "use directly in HTML", therefore danfo "works in the browser", right? In general I think a "NodeJS library" can be made to "works in a browser" .... At least I think *most of these packages will work in the browser*, but I'll check...

Comment: In order to get danfojs and pandas-js working in the context of an nextjs application, I had to addtionally install babel-cli: **npm install babel-cli --save** Also see http://github.com/StratoDem/pandas-js/issues/54

Comment: Filter syntax danfojs vs pandas-js:
danfojs: **df.query(df['id_parameter'].eq(idParameter))**, pandas-js: **df.filter(df.get('id_parameter').eq(idParameter))**  and delete column syntax:´danfojs: **df.drop({ columns: ['id_parameter'], axis: 1 });**, pandas-js: **???** => also a reason to prefer danfojs

Comment: danfo-js does not seem to support multi column index:
https://github.com/javascriptdata/danfojs/issues/496

Comment: Nice list. Here's the [npmtrends](https://npmtrends.com/danfojs-vs-data-forge-vs-dataframe-vs-dataframe-js-vs-js-data-vs-jsdataframe-vs-pandas-js-vs-pyodide) for anyone struggling to pick or narrow down the choices.

Answer (score 11):

I've been working on a data wrangling library for JavaScript called data-forge. It's inspired by LINQ and Pandas.

It can be installed like this:

```
npm install --save data-forge
```

Your example would work like this:

```
var csvData = "Source,col1,col2,col3\n" +
    "foo,1,2,3\n" +
    "bar,3,4,5\n";

var dataForge = require('data-forge');
var dataFrame = 
    dataForge.fromCSV(csvData)
        .parseInts([ "col1", "col2", "col3" ])
        ;
```

If your data was in a CSV file you could load it like this:

```
var dataFrame = dataForge.readFileSync(fileName)
    .parseCSV()
    .parseInts([ "col1", "col2", "col3" ])
    ;
```

You can use the `select` method to transform rows.

You can extract a column using `getSeries` then use the `select` method to transform values in that column.

You get your data back out of the data-frame like this:

```
var data = dataFrame.toArray();
```

To average a column:

```
 var avg = dataFrame.getSeries("col1").average();
```

There is much more you can do with this.

You can find more documentation on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/data-forge).

Answer (score 10):

**Ceaveat** The following is applicable only to d3 v3, and not the latest d4v4!

I am partial to [d3.js](http://d3js.org/), and while it won't be a total replacement for Pandas, if you spend some time learning its paradigm, it should be able to take care of all your data wrangling for you. (And if you wind up wanting to display results in the browser, it's ideally suited to that.)

Example. My CSV file `data.csv`:

```
name,age,color
Mickey,65,black
Donald,58,white
Pluto,64,orange
```

In the same directory, create an `index.html` containing the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>My D3 demo</title>

    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

      <script charset="utf-8" src="demo.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and also a `demo.js` file containing the following:

```js
d3.csv('/data.csv',

       // How to format each row. Since the CSV file has a header, `row` will be
       // an object with keys derived from the header.
       function(row) {
         return {name : row.name, age : +row.age, color : row.color};
       },

       // Callback to run once all data's loaded and ready.
       function(data) {
         // Log the data to the JavaScript console
         console.log(data);

         // Compute some interesting results
         var averageAge = data.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
           return prev + curr.age;
         }, 0) / data.length;

         // Also, display it
         var ulSelection = d3.select('body').append('ul');
         var valuesSelection =
             ulSelection.selectAll('li').data(data).enter().append('li').text(
                 function(d) { return d.age; });
         var totalSelection =
             ulSelection.append('li').text('Average: ' + averageAge);
       });
```

In the directory, run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8181`, and open http://localhost:8181 in your browser to see a simple listing of the ages and their average.

This simple example shows a few relevant features of d3:

- Excellent support for ingesting online data ([CSV](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV#csv), TSV, JSON, etc.)
- Data wrangling smarts baked in
- Data-driven DOM manipulation (maybe the hardest thing to wrap one's head around): your data gets transformed into DOM elements.

Comment: just to help future newbies - above instructions are no longer valid for d3 v4. think the mapping stage is done within the data callback now e.g. https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv/blob/master/README.md#csvParseRows

Comment: @swyx thanks for heads up, can you correct the example and post as answer?

Comment: @AhmedFasih You should correct your own post for the benefit of everyone. Also, swyx doesn't have enough reputation to edit your post.

Comment: @CarlesAlcolea I added a big disclaimer at the top, sorry I don’t have time to get up to speed on the current API right now 

Comment: @AhmedFasih well that's better than before :) Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

@neversaint your wait is over. say welcome to [Danfo.js](https://danfo.jsdata.org/) which is pandas like Javascript library built on tensorflow.js and supports tensors out of the box. This means you can convert danfo data structure to Tensors. And you can do groupby, merging, joining, plotting and other data processing.

Answer (score 7):

[Pandas.js](https://stratodem.github.io/pandas.js-docs/#introduction)
at the moment is an experimental library, but seems very promising it uses under the hood immutable.js and NumpPy logic, both data objects series and DataFrame are there..

**10-Feb-2021 Update** as @jarthur mentioned it seems no update on this repo for last 4 years

Comment: It looks like the library hasn't had a commit in over two years, and seems to have many issues. I wouldn't say 'very promising'.

Answer (score 6):

Below is Python numpy and pandas

```

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data_frame = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 4), ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], [1, 2, 3, 4])

data_frame[5] = np.random.randint(1, 50, 5)

print(data_frame.loc[['C', 'D'], [2, 3]])

# axis 1 = Y | 0 = X
data_frame.drop(5, axis=1, inplace=True)

print(data_frame)
```

```

The same can be achieved in JavaScript* [**numjs works only with Node.js**]
But D3.js has much advanced Data file set options. Both numjs and Pandas-js still in works..

```js
import np from 'numjs';
import { DataFrame } from 'pandas-js';

const df = new DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 4), ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], [1, 2, 3, 4])

// df
/*

          1         2         3         4
A  0.023126  1.078130 -0.521409 -1.480726
B  0.920194 -0.201019  0.028180  0.558041
C -0.650564 -0.505693 -0.533010  0.441858
D -0.973549  0.095626 -1.302843  1.109872
E -0.989123 -1.382969 -1.682573 -0.637132

*/
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the closest thing are libraries like:

- [ReclineJS](http://okfnlabs.org/recline/)
- [Miso Project Dataset](http://misoproject.com/dataset/)

Recline in particular has a Dataset object with a structure somewhat similar to Pandas data frames. It then allows you to connect your data with "Views" such as a data grid, graphing, maps etc. Views are usually thin wrappers around existing best of breed visualization libraries such as D3, Flot, SlickGrid etc.

Here's an example for Recline:

```
// Load some data
var dataset = recline.Model.Dataset({
  records: [
    { value: 1, date: '2012-08-07' },
    { value: 5, b: '2013-09-07' }
  ]
  // Load CSV data instead
  // (And Recline has support for many more data source types)
  // url: 'my-local-csv-file.csv',
  // backend: 'csv'
});

// get an element from your HTML for the viewer
var $el = $('#data-viewer');

var allInOneDataViewer = new recline.View.MultiView({
  model: dataset,
  el: $el
});
// Your new Data Viewer will be live!
```

Answer (score 3):

It's the year 2023 of the Common Era, and we have [Pyodide](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/), which is a cross-compilation of the entire CPython kernel, plus a large chunk of the numeric Python ecosystem, to WebAssembly (wasm) in order to run in browsers/Node.js. This of course includes Pandas, so see for example ["Pandas Tutor: Using Pyodide to Teach Data Science at Scale"](https://blog.pyodide.org/posts/pandastutor/) for what you can build with Pandas + Pyodide, and the [full list](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/usage/packages-in-pyodide.html) of packages that come out-of-the-box with Pyodide.

For Node, this is it. Pandas via Pyodide is the answer. For browsers… there are some challenges that have more to do with the fundamental nature of browsers than anything with the Pyodide stack. For example, the easiest way to load a CSV file into Pandas is to do a web request (see https://github.com/joyceerhl/vscode-pyolite/issues/12 and references therein), and similarly there are challenges with "saving" data (if you can, POST it to a server, but that's extra setup—no doubt Dropbox/Google Drive/etc. integrations are coming soon).

But in the nearly 8 years since this question was asked, no JavaScript package has even come close to bringing us Pandas, and here we are: Pandas has come to us. Hallelujah.

Answer (score 2):

Arquero is a library for handling relational data, with syntax similar to the popular R package `dplyr` (which is a sort of SQL-like).
https://observablehq.com/@uwdata/introducing-arquero

Answer (score 2):

There is a new JavaScript package called [Jandas](https://github.com/frlender/Jandas), which I think has has better indexing experience than other packages. It supports DataFrame with zero rows/columns in the shape of (0,n) or (n,0) and index with duplicated values. Comprehensive overloads on indexing functions ensures proper return type in TypeScript. Some examples:

```
const df = new DataFrame([[1,2],
                      [3,4],
                      [5,6]],
       {index:['a','b','b'],columns:['d',5]})
df.iloc(null,0) //output: new Series([1,3,5],{index:['a','b','b'],name:'d'})
df.iloc([0,1]).values //output: [[1,2],[3,4]]
df.iloc([2],[1]).values // [[6]]
df.iloc(-1).values // [5,6]
df.iloc([-3,-1]).values //[[1,2],[5,6]]

df.iloc(':2').values // [[1,2],[3,4]]
df.iloc('-3:-1').values //[[1,2],[3,4]]
df.iloc('::-1').values //[[5,6],[3,4],[1,2]]

df.iloc([true,false,false]).values // [[1,2]]
df.iloc([false,false,false]) // new DataFrame([],{index:[],columns:['d',5]})
df.iloc(null,[false,false]) // new DataFrame([[],[],[]],{index:['a','b','b'],columns:[]})

df.loc(['a']).values // [[1,2]]
df.loc('a').values // [1,2]
df.loc('b').values // [[3,4],[5,6]]
df.loc(null,['d',5]).values // [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
df.loc(null,[true,false]).values //[[1],[3],[5]]
```

It implements query functions that are perhaps more powerful than that in Pandas:

```
const ss = new Series([1,2,3],{index:['a','b','b'],name:'kk'})
ss.b('x > 2') // output is: [false,false,true]
ss.q('x>2') // output is: new Series([3],{index:['b'],name:'kk'})
ss.q('x>=1 && x<3').values // [1,2]

const df = new DataFrame([[1,2,3],
                          [3,8,9],
                          [5,6,7]],
        {index:['a','b','b'],columns:['5',5,'e']})
df.b('[ "5" ]>3') // output: [false,false,true]
df.b('["a"]<=2',0) // [true,true,false]
df.q('["5"]>3') //output: new DataFrame([[5,6,7]],
                //     {index:['b'],columns:['5',5,'e']})

// pandas query function does not support numeric column names.
df.q('[5]>3') //output: new DataFrame([[3,8,9],[5,6,7]],
              //        {index:['b','b'],columns:['5',5,'e']})

df.q('[ "a"]>1 && ["a"]<3',null)
// output: new DataFrame([[2],[8],[6]],{index:['a','b','b'],columns:[5]})

df.q('[ "a" ]>1','[ 5 ]>3') //output: new DataFrame([[8,9],[6,7]],
                        //       {index:['b','b'],columns:[5,'e']})

const dx = new DataFrame<number|string>(
               [[1,'e',3],
                [3,'a',9],
                [5,'c',7]],
  {index:['a','b','b'],columns:['5',5,'e']})

dx.q('["a","c"].includes([5]) && ["e"]>7')
//output: new DataFrame<number|string>([[3,'a',9]],
//        {index:['b'],columns:['5',5,'e']})
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an dynamic approach assuming an existing header on line 1. The csv is loaded with `d3.js`.

```
function csvToColumnArrays(csv) {

    var mainObj = {},
    header = Object.keys(csv[0]);

    for (var i = 0; i < header.length; i++) {

        mainObj[header[i]] = [];
    };

    csv.map(function(d) {

        for (key in mainObj) {
            mainObj[key].push(d[key])
        }

    });        

    return mainObj;

}


d3.csv(path, function(csv) {

    var df = csvToColumnArrays(csv);         

});
```

Then you are able to access each column of the data similar an R, python or Matlab dataframe with `df.column_header[row_number]`.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy to parse CSV in javascript because each line's already essentially a javascript array. If you load your csv into an array of strings (one per line) it's pretty easy to load an array of arrays with the values:

```
var pivot = function(data){
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        for (var j=0; j < data[i].length; j++){
            if (i === 0){
                result[j] = [];
            }
            result[j][i] = data[i][j];
        }
    }
    return result;
};

var getData = function() {
    var csvString = $(".myText").val();
    var csvLines = csvString.split(/\n?$/m);

    var dataTable = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < csvLines.length; i++){
        var values;
        eval("values = [" + csvLines[i] + "]");
        dataTable[i] = values;
    }

    return pivot(dataTable);
};
```

Then `getData()` returns a multidimensional array of values by column.

I've demonstrated this in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daiopowen/xn53u2t4/) for you.

Of course, you can't do it quite this easily if you don't trust the input - if there could be script in your data which eval might pick up, etc.

Comment: I know you put a warning in your answer, but I really can't stress enough how bad this method is from a security point of view.

Comment: It's only bad from a security point of view if he doesn't trust the input. If, for example, he is doing a school project in which he already knows his input files (because he or his teacher has provided them ahead of time in a specific format), this is a compact, easy, and, legible solution. He didn't give any context regarding the source of his inputs, just ask for a way to read the CSV in for easy processing.

Comment: It would be trivial to include validation in any case or even as a prior job step.  Node people will be reading this too,

Comment: "It would be trivial to include validation in any case or even as a prior job step". Javascript is turing-complete by only using special characters. You'd have to disable all sorts of special characters, and then hope you didn't screw up the regex, or whatever method you use to validate/sanitize. Never use eval.

Comment: "It's only bad from a security point of view if he doesn't trust the input", when exactly would you ever trust input? Whenever input comes from somewhere else (uploads, people, file system), that input is untrusted.

Comment: "a school project". Lets not encourage learning worst-practice code in school.

Comment: Apart from the severe security problems with this, this can't even parse CSV lines if they don't feature quotes: `const line = "foo,bar"; eval("values = [" + line + "]");` will crash. This is absolutely terrible.