# Resampling time series or dataframes with Javascript / Node.js

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, pandas, resampling

I need to resample time series in `node.js`. So I would like to know whether there is a tool in `javascript` which works similar as `pandas` in Python?

Lets say I have data which looks similar to this example:

```
[{
    "time": "28-09-2018 21:29:04",
    "value1": 1280,
    "value2": 800
},
{   
    "time": "28-09-2018 21:38:56",
    "value1": 600,
    "value2": 700
},
{
    "time": "29-09-2018 10:40:00",
    "value1": 1100,
    "value2": 300
},
{
    "time": "29-09-2018 23:50:48",
    "value1": 140,
    "value2": 300
}]
```

In `Python` I would put this data into a `pandas` dataframe and then resample it into a new dataframe with a different sample rate. In this example to daily data:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame(...)
df_days = df.resample('1440min').apply({'value1':'sum', 'value2':'sum'}).fillna(0)
```

So my new data would look something like this:

```
[{
    "time": "28-09-2018 00:00:00",
    "value1": 1880,
    "value2": 1500
},
{   
    "time": "29-09-2018 00:00:00",
    "value1": 1240,
    "value2": 600
}]
```

What is in general the best way to do this in `node.js` / `javascript` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Pandas equivalent in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30610675/python-pandas-equivalent-in-javascript)

Comment: have you found a way to solve this?

Comment: Yes, I export the data as an excel sheet and then execute a python script, which loads the data and performs resampling on it. I can post the code if you like. Unfortunately I couldn't find a native nodejs solution.

Comment: @baermathias I'm trying to do something similar, would you mind posting the code?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need a node.js/JS library for this task. What you want to achieve can be done with a [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function.

```js
var a = [{
    "time": "28-09-2018 21:29:04",
    "value1": 1280,
    "value2": 800
},
{   
    "time": "28-09-2018 21:38:56",
    "value1": 600,
    "value2": 700
},
{
    "time": "29-09-2018 10:40:00",
    "value1": 1100,
    "value2": 300
},
{
    "time": "29-09-2018 23:50:48",
    "value1": 140
}];

var b = Object.values(a.reduce((container, current) => {
  var date = current['time'].substring(0, 10);
  if (!container[date])
    container[date] = {time: date + ' 00:00:00', value1: current['value1'] || 0, value2: current['value2'] || 0};
  else {
    container[date]['value1'] += current['value1'] || 0;
    container[date]['value2'] += current['value2'] || 0;
  }
  return container;
}, {}));
```

This function create an object with keys the date and aggregate the values. You need to take care if the date exists or not in that object. With `|| 0` you manage if the property is not in a element to not break anything; and with `Object.values` you extract the values to have an array. Since you used the date as string I treated them as string but if they are Date object you have to adjust the common part where you declare `date`.

Side note, as always you can reference to a prop in js with `['value1']` or also with `.value1`. I stick to a more familiar pythonic syntax since it was mentioned.

Of course, this is just an example with daily resample, if you need a bigger/smaller quota you have to manipulate dates. Let's say we want to emulate a 12 hours resample, you write:

```js
var resample = 12;
var b = Object.values(a.reduce((container, current) => {
  var date = new Date(current['time'].replace(/(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+) (\d+):(\d+):(\d+)/, '$3-$2-$1T$4:$5:$6'));
  date.setHours(Math.floor(date.getHours() / resample) * resample);
  date.setMinutes(0);
  date.setSeconds(0);
  if (!container[date.toString()])
    container[date.toString()] = {time: date, value1: current['value1'] || 0, value2: current['value2'] || 0};
  else {
    container[date.toString()]['value1'] += current['value1'] || 0;
    container[date.toString()]['value2'] += current['value2'] || 0;
  }
  return container;
}, {}));
```

That regex `replace` is because the dates are not in ISO format, you could use a library for that, like *moment* or others, I wanted to show that it is possible to do all with just plain JS.

Remember one thing when using JS dates: if you are in the browser the timezone is the one of the client, if you are in a server the timezone is the same of the server. If `time` is timezone free I don't think there should be problems because it is all managed in the local timezone.

Answer (score 0):

Simple approach

1. very simple `flask` app that can do `pandas` processing for you
2. simple `JQuery` AJAX to use it.

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, viewport-fit=cover">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <main id="main">
        <section id="data-section">
            <h2>Data</h2>
            <div id="data"/>
        </section>
    </main>
</body>
<script>
    function apicall(url, data) {
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST", url:url, data:{data:JSON.stringify(data)},
            success: (data) => { $("#data").text(JSON.stringify(data)); }
        });
    }
    data = [{"time": "28-09-2018 21:29:04","value1": 1280,"value2": 800},{"time": "28-09-2018 21:38:56","value1": 600,"value2": 700},{"time": "29-09-2018 10:40:00","value1": 1100,"value2": 300},
            {"time": "29-09-2018 23:50:48","value1": 140,"value2": 300}];
    window.onload = function () {
        apicall("/handle_data", data);
    }
</script>
</html>
```

### Flask App

```
import pandas as pd, json
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request, render_template, Response

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/handle_data', methods=["POST"])
def handle_data():
    df = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(request.form.get("data")))
    df["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time"])
    df.set_index("time", inplace=True)
    df = df.resample('1440min').apply({'value1':'sum', 'value2':'sum'}).fillna(0)
    return Response(json.dumps(df.to_dict(orient="records")),
                    mimetype="text/json")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=3000)
```

### output

[image]

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. It may use javascript, but the question is for a JS library that is equivalent to pandas for aggregation.

Comment: @SidKwakkel it's a full stack answer.  It's so simple to build and deploy to any cloud stack (AWS EB, GCloud, Azure).  Effectively heterogeneous micro services.  Homogeneous solutions quite often land up more complicated

Comment: Nice idea, this could even be a cloud function