# JavaScript equivalent to Pandas read_csv and to_markdown?

Tags: javascript, csv, markdown

I have seen [Python Pandas equivalent in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30610675/python-pandas-equivalent-in-javascript) - but I've tried looking up the libraries listed there, and seeing if they have the required methods, and so far I cannot find anything; I'm hoping someone more knowledgeable might point out, if there is something out there I can use.

Here is a minimal Python example:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# example from https://stackoverflow.com/q/22604564
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    from StringIO import StringIO
else:
    from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd

TESTDATA = StringIO("""col1,col2,col3
    1,4.4,99
    2,4.5,200
    3,4.7,65
    4,3.2,140
    """)

df = pd.read_csv(TESTDATA) #, sep=",")

print("Usual text representation of table:")
print()
print(df)

print()

print("Markdown text representation of table:")
print()
print(df.to_markdown()) # example from https://stackoverflow.com/q/33181846
```

When I run this, I get:

```
$ python3 test.py
Usual text representation of table:

   col1  col2  col3
0     1   4.4    99
1     2   4.5   200
2     3   4.7    65
3     4   3.2   140

Markdown text representation of table:

|    |   col1 |   col2 |   col3 |
|---:|-------:|-------:|-------:|
|  0 |      1 |    4.4 |     99 |
|  1 |      2 |    4.5 |    200 |
|  2 |      3 |    4.7 |     65 |
|  3 |      4 |    3.2 |    140 |
```

So, is there a client-side JavaScript library with an "easy" API that will allow me to do `read_csv` (either from an in-memory string, or file contents via XMLHttpRequest) and converts it into an in-memory table representation - and then allows me to do `to_markdown`, so the in-memory table representation is output as a Markdown-formatted table string?

Comment: that's like 5 or 10 lines of code, do you really need a library for it?

Comment: perhaps https://github.com/javascriptdata/danfojs

Comment: I would use the d3 library. In particular: https://d3js.org/d3-dsv